# Local, regular file causes `stat` or `ls -l` to hang

Tags: ls, freeze, stat

I've seen a [few](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35322/ls-taking-long-time-in-small-directory) different [questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/367438/ls-hangs-for-a-certain-directory) about `ls` hanging.  It's usually because they use the `-l` switch, which causes a `stat` on the file, which in turn is a bad symlink or pointing to an NFS mount or some such.

I have a local file (in an old copy of the Git source that somebody else unpacked, of all things) that causes `stat` to hang, but responds to <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd>.  It also causes `ls -l` to hang, hard, such that it does not respond to `kill` (but does terminate on a `kill -9`).

It's not a symlink.  The other files in the directory appear to `stat` without issue.  I've recently rebooted the machine with forced `fsck`, which came out clean, and `dmesg` shows no disk-related messages.  How can this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a problem in getting the user name or group name, if you use and LDAP or NIS or other sources for that. What are you `passwd` and `group` lines in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`? This may be the case if an `ls -nl` return immediately.

Comment: Unless it is looking for extra sources for that data when something isn't found, it would hang all the time (i.e., get the name, return it; don't get it, return anyway). Isn't too plausible. Perhaps the file is somehow messed up (and a `fsck(8)` might be in order)?

Comment: Right, but he might have long timeouts. So this is still a possibility.

Comment: I said _not plausible_, not that it was out of question.

Comment: Some other ridiculous ideas: A symlink to somewhere strange? `stat` (no switches) say anything?

Comment: The crazy part is that `stat` hangs *after* printing that this is a normal file, nothing to see here, move along.  Closes with a ctrl-C though.

Comment: @eppesuig, you nailed it.  I have no idea why but that file (and one or two others) were owned by a non-existent user/group (confirmed by checking `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`; `/etc/nsswitch.conf` was just `files db`).  I `chown`'d the files back to root:root and my `ll` doesn't hang.  Thanks!

Comment: Of course that raises another question: is there a version of `ls` that doesn't die in a flaming car wreck when it finds a file with bad ownership info?  That seems a little... excessive.

Comment: Usually, you only have `compat` or `files`. If you also have `db`, than you may investigate further in order to find what is wrong there.

Comment: I mis-typed, it was actually `files` and `ldap` -- which is strange, because the examples don't list `ldap` as an option and anyway this server isn't using networked logins.  I inherited this box and it's been neglected for a year or two (and poorly documented before that!) so I may indeed have some digging to do.

Comment: Just a follow up if anybody comes across this later.  It looks like `ldap` is a valid value, but I'd guess the machine's `ldap` configuration had fallen into disrepair.  While I figure out what's going on there, I fixed the `ls` / `stat` freezes by changing from `passwd: files ldap` to `passwd: files db`.